# expected expression before ; syntax error in C

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-errors, syntax-error

why I get compliation error

```
error: expected expression before ‘;’ token
```

Why `(void)` can not be an expression?

```
int main()
{
    (void);
    return 0;
}
```

After I added 1 after `(void)` it works but I don't know why `(void)` alone does not.

Comment: `(void)` is not a valid expression in C. I am not quite sure what you were trying to do but as it does nothing, you can just omit the `(void);` After adding the `1` is casting the 1 to the "type" `void` which is only usefil when you don't want to see an `unused variable` warning.

Comment: Because there is no expression to be `void`. The part of the statement after the typecast is empty.

Comment: I am trying to remove function call in specific scenario by #define it with nothing and void will be left alone

Comment: @AhmedSalama That sounds like an misunderstanding of (or don't know how to use) preprocessor. You probably need to ask *that* question instead.

Comment: Also there is never any need to cast anything to `void`, other than to avoid warnings about ignoring the return value, which you shouldn't be doing in the first place. NB the [tag:windows] tag has exactly nothing to do with it. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: That line isn't needed at all, but if you do want a do-nothing statement (instead of nothing), use a bare semicolon (i.e., delete the `(void)` but keep the `;`.  If you instead want an expression statement that does nothing, you can use `0;` by itself, or you can cast it to void with `(void)0;`.  Without some expression after the cast operator, it's invalid syntax, just as `-;` is invalid but `-1;` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do there is called typecasting, it allows us to change the data type of a variable during runtime. The right way to do it is like this :

```
int main()
{
    float fvar = 14.2;
    int   ivar = (int)fvar;
    return 0;
}
```

What I did here is that i assigned a `float` variable to an `int` by casting `fvar` to the same data type as `ivar`.

And when you wrote `void()`, you were just trying to call a function named void that doesn't exist, which causes an error.